# Anyone knows what does highlight mean in svn revision view of zend studio?

Tags: svn, zend-studio

[image]

I'm confused what the line in bold means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using TortoiseSVN. TortoiseSVN uses boldface in its log window to show what revision your working directory is updated to.